# Printing works from Writer but not Evince/Okular etc. (Filter error)

Tags: printing, pdf, hplip, postscript

i recently got a used printer (HP LaserJet 2200dn) that i try to use with Ubuntu 12.10. The thing is, that whatever i try, i cannot print pdf's (neither with Evince nor Okular). Printing from LibreOffice Writer works like a charm though. I do have the HPLIP toolbox.

Anyone any ideas?

Edit: I forgot to add that when i'm trying to print a pdf it actually prints two pages: one is completely empty, on the other it states:

```
ERROR: invalidaccess 
OFFENDING COMMAND: filter 
STACK: /SubFileDecode 
endstream
0
--nostringval--
--nostringval--
21
false
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution:

- I've uninstalled hplip: `sudo apt-get remove hplip`
- Delete the printer.
- Add the printer again.

There is a bug inside the package hplip which is supposed to provide drivers for HP printers.
Now it works but in another hand I do not have all the functionality for my printer.